# Bootstrap Login/Register form - How to go to specific form tab on redirect

Tags: php, html, class, redirect

I am using a bootstrap login/registration form. It is this form:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-and-register-tabbed-form

It is a tabbed form. When a user attempts to register, the email address is checked against a mysql database via php. If the email address is already registered, I have a php variable that displays. The problem is, when you are redirected back to the register form, the first thing you see is the Login tab. So the user never see why they were taken back unless they click the register tab. Then they can see the message that was generated.  How can i redirect back to the Register tab using php??

I have tried moving the class="active" from the login-form-link to the register-form-link, but that did not work.

Can this be accomplished with php after redirect or would it be simpler to just keep my login page and my registration page separate?

Full Code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form id="login-form" action="https://phpoll.com/login/process" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="https://phpoll.com/recover" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form id="register-form" action="https://phpoll.com/register/process" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you see the source code in your bootsnip, there are two forms in there. There is javascript controlling which one is shown, by editing their respective inline styles. `style="display:none;"` and `style="display:block"`

This is what you need to change, and not the active class of the link that is referring to the active form. Or, for the better, edit your code to alter them both. Set the respective link to active, and set `display: none;` to the block that shouldn't be displayed, and `display: block;` to the one that should be.

Comment: Thanks! That is much simpler than I thought. I'll just write an if/else depending on if there is an error session variable being passed from my "checkregistration.php" file. I appreciate it!